# Article on developers doing project management and velocity

Tags: software-development, velocity

Are there any specific blogs on developers doing project management related to developer throwing away project management for a 2-4 week period to speed things up temporarily?

My CEO is asking since he does not understand why one of our team leads would stop doing his PM responsibilities to speed up the project.  He thinks it would 100% of the time slow down the project.

Context: We have a team lead who for 2 iterations(with my approval to do this only temporary) could stop his 3-5 days per iteration of project management and concentrate on delivery.   My CEO thinks this actually slows things down (and long term it definitely does but shorter term, I am wondering if there are blog articles on this to give to my CEO)

thanks,
Dean

Comment: You keep asking about this situation with your CEO and querying for documents or research to give him. If someone is working on two things at once, it's only logical that they can do just one of the activities better now by focusing on that alone. Any child that had homework to do understands the concept. Why can't your CEO?

Comment: In addition to being a close duplicate of https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/32792/4271, search-type questions and WorkplaceSE-type “how do I convince people” questions are generally off-topic on PMSE.

Comment: @Bogdan I often bridge the gap between biz and tech. and the amount of 'common sense' I have to explain is unreal sometimes.  You have to remain patient and try your best.

Comment: yes @Todd I apologize but was hoping to change this post into an 'ask for information' which I thought I did 'only' with back drop on context is all.  There is not a single "how do I convince people" in this one 'I thought'.  It was very related to your ask on cleaning up the question.   (I have very limited time as we go through funding right now).

Answer (score 1):

### You or someone else should take over the PM role for this 2-4 week period

PMs handle all the planning, coordination and communication including stakeholder communication.

It is not a valid assumption that somehow this is superfluous and the team will run on auto-pilot in the absence of this PM role (even if temporary).

Depending on how critical the PM's role is in your project and your team, at best it will cause frustration to the team members leading to avoidable arguments and drop in morale and team spirit which will be very hard to recover from. And at worst it can jeopardize the delivery itself, which is what you are trying to speed up.

> with my approval to do this only temporary

Looks like you have an oversight role for this team. You can ask the PM to handover charge to you for this brief period and focus on development.

Comment: at a small/mid-sized company, I 100% agree.  We are a startup and sometimes startups are close to the breaking point and typically you hire correctly so communication is still happening between all parties if the culture is setup right.  I have less time than our team leads as I play CTO and doing investor pitches while playing architect, doing some product and sales and coding(I am stretched way way tooooo thin for that solution to be reliable for me in the NEAR term - after this funding round, though I think we get back to nearly always doing PM)